# Feathersjs. How do i redirect initial page to page in view folder instead of public folder

Tags: html, feathersjs

Writing my first Feathersjs app. Using handlebars for templating. HTML Templates in Express seem to default to a view folder. It seems Feathersjs defaults to a CLI generated public folder. How can i tell Feathersjs to use my view folder for HTML? That will allow me to put all my HTML templates in that folder.

Comment: Have you checked https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/configuration.html#example ?

Comment: I have changed the public key in the default.json to ../views and moved "index.html" to that folder calling it "index.handlebars". I now get a 404.

Comment: Got it working. So simple i'm embarrassed. I needed to add a 'get' route to url path '/' and in the handler render the index page...  thx all...